# Simplemodal Google Map displays once but not on 2nd Click

Tags: google-maps-api-3, modal-dialog, kml

I've done well by my standards! I have pretty much zero knowledge of JS other than the basics of Functions etc. Ive used these pages to pull together a working script that loads Google Maps into a Modal using the SimpleModal framework. To my relief I got it working but it has one final bug that I cannot shift. The Modal loads on the first click of the HREF but if I close the modal and then try to reopen it it loads the modal with parts of the map missing. The missing map issue was a problem i thought I had already solved. My JS is

```
            var map;
        var src = 'https://sites.google.com/site/bristol2monaco/kml/route2.kml';
        function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.337890,-0.813049);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("basic-modal-content"), {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
        loadKmlLayer(src, map);
  }

        function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        clickable: false,
        preserveViewport: true,
        map: map
      });
    } 
  initialize();
```

and the js file that registers the 'click' contains:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Load dialog on page load
//$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

// Load dialog on click
$('#table .newbasic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 
    map.setCenter(center);
    return false;
});
});
```

As i thought i had already solved the missing map bug (using solutions posted here) with the (map, resize) line above none of the solutions on here help. Do i have to reinitialise the map or something. Grateful for advice.

Comment: Try resetting the bounds.  `map.fitBounds(map.getBounds());`

Comment: I tried your code after the map.setCenter line, it didn't work, is that the correct place to insert it? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: That should be fine. Fixed a similar issue for me though I re-applied my marker bounds. If you can put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) others might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the modal to open use the onOpen Function described by Eric Martin. With using his onOpen function you will be able to use the callback feature and thusly use the google map event-listener to listen for the resize event. Once the resize event has been heard, you can reinitialize your google map thusly removing the gray areas

```
    $("#table .newbasic").modal({
       onOpen: function (dialog) {
          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'resize', function() {
             //Alert TESTING IF RESIZE is heard(remove after test)
             alert("heard resize onOpen");
             initialize();                  
             map.setCenter(center);
          });
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");   
       }
    });
```